# How to get Android Pie style recent apps on Android 5?

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, customization

I'm back with another question. Let's make it simple. I want to have the horizontal style recent apps view ie Android 9+ style recent apps view in my rooted Android 5.1 phone. I have searched both on Google and YouTube but no solutions found. Any answers to this?

I am looking forward to the community's answers.

Edit:
After a comment from William, I am adding the picture of what I mean.

Recent apps preview:
How I have it now:
[image: Android 5 Recent Apps View]

How I want to have it:
[image: Android 9 Recent Apps View]

I hope this helps to further understand my question.

Comment: System-wide customization usually needs root or even custom ROM. I don't think this can be solved only with apps.

Comment: I've already mentioned that I have root. So, any solutions now?

Comment: Could you add a picture I'm not sure what you mean.